# Javascript - How to remove the style attribute from all <li> tags

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove the style attribute from all li tags using only javascript?

```
<ul>
   <li style="color: red;">Item 1</li>
   <li style="color: red;">Item 2</li>
   <li style="color: red;">Item 3</li>
   <li style="color: red;">Item 4</li>
   <li style="color: red;">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function removeAttrByTagName(tagname, attribute)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
    var i;

    for(i = 0;  i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i].removeAttribute(attribute);
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like this `removeAttrByTagName('li', 'style')`

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ex9QB/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Using modern browsers:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), function (a) {
    a.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4dG2z/1/).

Comment: I want to do this inside a onclick = function() {}
How do I do then. Thanks

Comment: In `onclick` of which specific element?

Comment: Okay I found the code I was looking for. Thanks for your help :)